# Callback URL not approved for this client application. Approved callback URLs can be adjusted in your application settings

Tags: angular, twitter-oauth, auth0

I need to enable my website users to login to my website using their twitter accounts. My website based on angular 8 and spring boot. While I'm configuring Auth0 and test my twitter app, I get the following error:

```
{
  "error": "access_denied",
  "error_description": "Callback URL not approved for this client application. Approved callback URLs can be adjusted in your application settings"
}
```

[image]

However I configured my callback_url correctly. So What is the fix of this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are most probably setting the twitter callback URL to your own domain, but in auth0 twitter login, the login callback should happen to auth0.

so change your twitter app callback URL to below,

```
https://your-tenant.auth0.com/login/callback
```

your-tenant should be replaced with your actual tenant domain.

More info here https://community.auth0.com/t/twitter-auth-no-longer-works/12291/22